# oracle view SYS.ALL_TAB_COLUMNS

Tags: view, oracle10g, etl

Aloha

Here's my purpose : I need to gather in a view some essential information about my OracleDB. What to do ? To use it in an ETL as a schema ressource I could query to qualify the data I'll translate and certify them.

I'm not logged as SYS. So, here's my view :

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "BRINDAVOINE".FME_SCHEMA_SIGE
   AS
   SELECT S.TABLE_NAME AS "feature_type",
          S.COLUMN_NAME AS "attribute_name",
          CASE S.DATA_TYPE
             WHEN 'BLOB'
             THEN
                'fme_buffer'
             WHEN 'CHAR'
             THEN
                CASE
                   WHEN S.DATA_LENGTH IS NULL THEN 'fme_char(400)'
                   ELSE 'fme_char(' || S.DATA_LENGTH || ')'
                END
             WHEN 'DATE'
             THEN
                'fme_date'
             WHEN 'NUMBER'
             THEN
                CASE
                   WHEN S.DATA_LENGTH IS NULL
                   THEN
                      'fme_decimal(400,'
                   ELSE
                         'fme_decimal('
                      || S.DATA_LENGTH
                      || ','
                      || CASE
                            WHEN S.DATA_PRECISION IS NULL THEN '2)'
                            ELSE S.DATA_PRECISION || ')'
                         END
                END
             WHEN 'VARCHAR2'
             THEN
                CASE
                   WHEN S.DATA_LENGTH IS NULL THEN 'fme_char(400)'
                   ELSE 'fme_char(' || S.DATA_LENGTH || ')'
                END
             WHEN 'NVARCHAR2'
             THEN
                CASE
                   WHEN S.DATA_LENGTH IS NULL THEN 'fme_char(400)'
                   ELSE 'fme_char(' || S.DATA_LENGTH || ')'
                END
             ELSE
                S.DATA_TYPE
          END
             AS "attribute_data_type",
          '' AS "geometry_type"
     FROM SYS.ALL_TAB_COLUMNS S
    WHERE     S.OWNER = 'A_REIMS'
          AND S.TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%RELATION'
          AND S.TABLE_NAME IN (SELECT NOM
                                 FROM A_DESIGN_REIMS.APICD_COMPOSANT
                                WHERE NUMERO_MODELE = 1 AND action != 2)
          AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE(S.COLUMN_NAME,
                              '(APIC_.*)|_([STXYLO]|S[GT]|[XY][12])$');
```

Unfortunately, I have an error message : A bad "ORA-04063: view "BRINDAVOINE.FME_SCHEMA_SIGE" comporte des erreurs" when I attempt to query it. I've tried an ALTER VIEW BRINDAVOINE.FME_SCHEMA_SIGE COMPILE but it didn't seem to change.

Here's my questions : is it ok to create a view from a sys."view" ? If so, why couldn't I create this view ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a view that queries a SYSTEM view. I was able to compile your view by removing the reference to A_DESIGN_REIMS.APICD_COMPOSANT (which of course is not present in my database).

Check for errors either by using the SQLPlus command "show errors" (immediately after creating the view), or by querying the "user_errors" or "all_errors" views. My guess is that the BRINDAVOINE user is missing a necessary privilege.